# iOS: Getting the Index of a character when it appears twice

Tags: ios, ios8, nsstring

If I have a string `NSString *string = "2.233.12";`  I need to trim everything after the second period, including the period itself.  So the result will be `"2.233"`.

If the string is `NSString *string = "2.3.19"`, the result will be "2.3"

If the string is `NSString *string = "2.50.99"`, the result will be "2.50"

What's the best way to accomplish this in Objective-C?